# How to clear the output everytime run code in VSCode? I'm using terminal in VSCode to run

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[I've try the coderunner extension setting but it's have an issues like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h5mq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add this your `settings.json`

```
  "debug.terminal.clearBeforeReusing": true
```

Then run your python file using VS Code Debugger, just hit `F5` then it will clear the terminal everytime you run the code. Tell me if it work!

Comment: i've also tried it, but the the output still have some bugs

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **code-runner**, first make sure you have installed the [code-runner extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner).

Select **Run Code** when using this extension for the first time:

[image]

Check the following in settings so that the last run result can be cleared automatically when running the file:

[image]

[image]

You can also add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,

"code-runner.runInTerminal": true

Comment: Does my solution solve your problem?